# Powershell calling psexec, script will halt until psexec is done, need to break this by time

Tags: powershell, break, psexec

I have the following code:

```
foreach ($program in $programlist){
        "$line installed $program" | Out-File "$logpath\log.txt" -Append

        psexec \\"$hostikname" -u bla\bla -p $plainpwd cmd /c "pushd $BucketPath & copy $program c:\programdata\"
        psexec \\"$hostikname" -i -u bla\bla -p $plainpwd -h cmd /c  "c:\programdata\$program"
        psexec \\"$hostikname" -u bla\bla -p $plainpwd cmd /c "del c:\programdata\$program"
       
       }
```

This is a part of script that we use to remote install programs on out client pc's.
works great only one problem:
script wont continue until it finish each psexec line. the script let the end user install the programs with admin right, it is interactive installation so the user is needed to be on the computer.
if for some reason one user call the script, and then goes for a cofee, script will stay stuck until the user will return and continue installation.
what i'd like to do is a check up - if for some reason one of the psexec lines is taking more than 2 minutes, id like to exit break break the psexec part and continue code.

how can i achive this?

Comment: you can use `start-job` to not wait for any of them

Comment: unfortunately this isn't good for the script as one psexec line is dependent on another, the main goal is like wait for X amount of minutes, if the script find that something is stuck in one of the psexec lines i want it to do something about it

Comment: What about a `do` `until` loop?

Comment: `$TimeStart = Get-Date
$TimeEnd = $timeStart.addminutes(2)
Write-Host "Start Time: $TimeStart"
write-host "End Time:   $TimeEnd"
Do { 
 
 $TimeNow = Get-Date
 if ($TimeNow -ge $TimeEnd) {

  Write-host "It's time to finish."

 } else {

  Write-Host "Not done yet, it's only $TimeNow"

 }

 Start-Sleep -Seconds 10

}
Until ($TimeNow -ge $TimeEnd)`

Comment: psexec will open installation on remote computer, when this happens, the script will continue only after the installation is done on the remote computer, if the user on the remote computer, doesn't do anything, meaning the installation will halt on remote computer, then the script wont move forward. i need to find a way to move forward after X minutes even if the end user isn't on his computer.. like a time counter for the psexec script block. after 10 minutes, break from the block and continue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Abraham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14903754/abraham-zinala) mentioned Start-Job is a viable solution to your problem.  Using Start-Job will allow you to start and monitor the job's progress/state.

```
    $allowedSecondsForCompletion = 120
    foreach ($program in $programlist) {
        "$line installed $program" | Out-File "$logpath\log.txt" -Append
    
        $timer = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
        $job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {  
            psexec \\"$hostikname" -u bla\bla -p $plainpwd cmd /c "pushd $BucketPath & copy $program c:\programdata\"
            psexec \\"$hostikname" -i -u bla\bla -p $plainpwd -h cmd /c "c:\programdata\$program"
            psexec \\"$hostikname" -u bla\bla -p $plainpwd cmd /c "del c:\programdata\$program"
        }
        
        while ($job.state -eq 'Running' -and $timer.ElapsedMilliseconds -lt ($allowedSecondsForCompletion * 1000))
        {
            start-sleep -Seconds 5
        }
    
        if ($job.State -ne 'Completed') {
            # check and Log failure
            
            # Terminate job if still running
            $job | Remove-Job -Force
            # or $job.StopJob()

        }
       
    }
```

Comment: I suggest to add `$job | Remove-Job` in case job finished successfully and `$job | Remove-Job -Force` in case timeout has been exceeded, so job will be forcefully killed.

Comment: Added suggestion by @zett42 to the answer.   Thank you zett42.